# Leading and Suffering Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, integer, permutations

### Introduction:

In Dutch, the words leading and suffering, being 'leiden' and 'lijden' respectively, are pronounced the same way. One is written with a "short ei", and one with a ["long ij"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_(digraph)), as we Dutchman would say, but both 'ei' and 'ij' are pronounced [ɛi].

### Challenge:

Given a list of numbers, determine which (if any) are leading, and which (if any) are suffering.

A leading number is:

- A positive number
- Has at least four digits
- Is in the highest 50% of the list in terms of value
- Is still in the highest 50% of the list in terms of value, if it's 3rd digit is replaced with its 2nd digit, and it's 2nd digit-position is filled with a 0 (i.e. `1234` would become `1024`)

A suffering number is:

- A negative number
- Has at least four digits
- Is in the lowest 50% of the list in terms of value
- Is still in the lowest 50% of the list in terms of value, if it's 3rd digit is replaced with its 2nd digit, and it's 2nd digit-position is filled with a 0 (i.e. `-4321` would become `-4031`)

**Example:**

Input: `[5827, 281993, 3918, 3854, -32781, -2739, 37819, 0, 37298, -389]`
Output: leading: `[5827, 281993, 37819, 37298]`; suffering: `[-32781, -2739]`

*Explanation:*

If we sort and split the numbers into two halves, it would be:

```
[[-32781, -2739, -389, 0, 3798], [3854, 3918, 5827, 37819, 281993]]
```

There are only two negative numbers with at least four digits: `[-32781, -2739]`. Changing the digits as described above wouldn't change their position, so they are both suffering numbers.
For the largest halve, all the numbers have at least four digits: `[3854, 3918, 5827, 37819, 281993]`. Changing the digits as described above would change some of their positions however. The `3854` would become `3084`, putting it below `3798` which is in the lowest 50%, so `3854` is not a leading number in this list. The same applies to `3918` which would become `3098`, also putting it below `3798`. The other three numbers are leading, as `5827` which would become `5087`, which is still above `3798` and is in fact still at the same index of the sorted list. So `[5827, 37819, 281993]` are the leading numbers.

### Challenge rules:

- I/O is flexible. Input-list can be a list of integers, 2D digit lists, list of strings, etc. Output can be a list of lists of integers, two separated lists, two strings, both printed to STDOUT, etc.
- When determining if a number is leading/suffering, we only look at its new position of that number if only its digits are changed accordingly, not after we've applied the modifications to all numbers.
- We output the original numbers, not the modified ones.
- The numbers in the leading and suffering output-lists can be in any order.
- If the size of the input-list is odd, the number at the center doesn't belong to either halve.
- Numbers are guaranteed to remain unique after its modification. So a list like `[0, 1, 1045, 1485]` isn't a valid input-list, since `1485` would be equal to `1045` after it's modification.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Input: [5827, 281993, 3918, 3854, -32781, -2739, 37819, 0, 37298, -389]
Output: leading: [5827, 281993, 37819, 37298]; suffering: [-32781, -2739]

Input: [-100, 472, 413, -1782]
Output: leading: []; suffering: [-1782]

Input: [-1234, -1235, -1236, 1234, 1235, 1236]
Output: leading: [1234, 1235, 1236]; suffering: [-1234, -1235, -1236]

Input: [-1919, -1819, -1719, -1619, -1500, -1444, 40, 4444, 18]
Output: leading: [4444]; suffering: []

Input: [-1004, -1111, -1000]
Output: leading: []; suffering: [-1111]

Input: [-1004, -1111, -1010, 1000]
Output: leading: [1000]; suffering: [-1111]

Input: [1000, -1000]
Output: leading: [1000]; suffering: [-1000]

Input: [1000, -5000, 4000]
Output: leading: [4000]; suffering: [-5000]
```

Comment: Judging from the test cases, it seems you mean for the 50% to round down when the list's length is odd. You might want to specify that explicitly.

Comment: Suggested test case: [1000, -1000]

Comment: @Grimy As for your first comment, the rule "_If the size of the input-list is odd, the number at the center doesn't belong to either halve_" should cover that, right? And added the suggested test case.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
(‚εÅmyεD1è0šāǝ}‹y*₄@Ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f41HDrHNbD7fmVp7b6mJ4eIXB0YVHGo/PrX3UsLNS61FTi8Ph/v//o00tjMx1FIwsDC0tjXUUjC0NLYCkhamJjoKusZG5hSGQNjI3tgQKAjlAygDEMrK0AMlbWMb@19XNy9fNSayqBAA)

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f41HDrHNbD608t/XwBMPDK4yOzz20zxBIrDvcmvuoYZfWo6YWh9rD/f//R@uaGhgY6BiCCBMgEftfVzcvXzcnsaoSAA) based on your current 23-byter

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I just edited my answer to another 22 I found independently. Now to see if we can combine those optimizations for a 21...

Comment: Probably not. I used the `©` and `®Åm` instead of your `ÅmUy` and `X` to save a byte, but you now removed the `UX` as well by doing the `Åm ... ‹y` after the map, so it's a similar optimization. I actually like yours better, since it doesn't use any unnecessary variables in that case. :)

Comment: Dang, very nice find with `0šāǝ`! :D Would have never thought of that!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! There's also `D¦0š2Lǝ`, which is the same byte-count as `D1è0šāǝ`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>119</s> <s>118</s> <s>111</s> 107 bytes

```python
lambda a:[[n for n in a if sorted(a)[::d][~len(a)/2]*d<int('0'.join(`n*d`[:2])+`n*d`[3:])>999]for d in-1,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BTsMwDIbvPIVva0cDsZMuSQW8SIi0oqxa0Uin0gsXXr04izRpCJGDP/u3/Tvnr@U4JVqH59f11H@8xR76zvsEwzRDgjFBD@MAn9O8HGLV177rYvDfp0Pi4pHCNj6Naak2cvPwPo2p2qdt3PuOQn1fUtWF@sU5F7JhZEOBDYb1PPMaDJVvLZkGyKJzqgHl0HK0rW5AKDIWmWSUY5ELhswZOZv71oX67uokUHJTG@KA7CXQWLodIJV9GW3BroGiFSkrtwsunxRoC0zBrqDN5wRqzfs6X75kaH//6XKSX4aU8t82ss9fQ1d5/QE)

Outputs as `suffering, leading`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 bytes

```
,NµD2ị;0Ʋ2,3¦ḌƊ>ẠɗƇÆṁ;999Ɗ)N2¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/H79BWF6OHu7utDY5tMtIxPrTs4Y6eY112D3ctODn9WPvhtoc7G60tLS2PdWn6GR1a9v9w@9FJD3fO@P8/WtfQ0tBSR0HX0AJCmUMoMwhlamAAokxMTHQUTIBMEzDL0AIoaGxpaB4LAA)

Given the length of [Grimy’s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186145/42248), I’m sure this can be golfed better, but here it is.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 162 bytes

```javascript
a=>[(g=i=>a.filter(n=>n*i>999&(h=t=>a.reduce((a,c)=>a+(c!=n&i*c<i*t(n)),0)>=a.length/2)(x=>x)&h(m=x=>x<0?-m(-x):x>999?m(x/10)*10+x%10:x-x%100+x/10%10)))(1),g(-1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLBcpswEL3zFeohHsmRCBIQpDgip34Fw4Eh2KaDIQNyh0yn3@7uirqJW6fhoLf79r2nZeBb9b2a6rF9caIfnpvT1p4qmxd0Z1ubV@G27Vwz0t7m/brNjTErurcOJ2PzfKwbSiteM@hvaf3F9qt2XT@2a0d7xnjEcluFXdPv3P5OMTrbfGarPT1YrB6jJ3GgYmYPM@Y@Heh8JyO2ltHtfCOjh1kgQAMsFIwxKhnfUSFZedoEXeOIayY3EUuKoChSrTJOlJbGxJzERmo4dZpwImKVaQmostgACQ1AhJUyGufalDz4O2GReU3JSXGRUoIe7hSwHydJpuCQ4BEy0wqjvME3Z6GKcROAdIF7ThZuoZBB478cuWb@E2twRyH1AtkC9wukuJyQSQLmBPf0ldR4D9aY/e5F/BXwIERR9PYa8HwkkxB7Fi94aUDuXd6bBIsLSeoh@S1MzsLUC4NyE/gPPg2jg@9dEZuTKsSO0pm/wv83i1cGIv9HhNth/FrVe4odSn8EhKB9OLqXIwZs/aiISvAQUg/9NHRN2A27D3l/lx/Kkl2fLulo/o9bfeK@lg7ET7Y5/QI)

Anonymous function that take an array of numbers as input and outputs a 2-element array as output. The first element in the output array is an array of leading numbers, the second element in the output array is an array of following numbers.

```javascript
// a: input array of numbers
a=>
  // begin output array
  [
    // define a function g with input i
    // when i is 1, generate leading
    // when i is -1, generate following
    (g=i=>
      // function g returns a subset of a,
      // use filter() to select elements
      a.filter(n=>
        // n must be 4 digits and explicitly
        // positive or negative depending
        // on whether we are calculating
        // leading or following numbers
        n*i>999&
        // function h determines whether
        // the current number is in the
        // larger or smaller half,
        // depending on whether we are
        // calculating the leading or
        // following numbers.
        // argument t defines a
        // transformation that should
        // be applied to th current number
        (h=t=>
          // use reduce() to count the
          // number of numbers greater or
          // less than the transformed
          // current number
          a.reduce((a,c)=>
            // add the current total to...
            a+
            // either 0 or 1 depending on
            // whether the transformed
            // current number is in the
            // opposite group (leading vs
            // following
            (c!=n&i*c<i*t(n)),0)>=
          // are at least half in the
          // opposite group?
          a.length/2)
          // invoke h with the identity
          // transform
          (x=>x)&
          // invoke h again with a
          // transform m that moves the
          // 2nd digit to the 3rd digit and
          // 0's out the 2nd digit.
          // input for m is number x
          h(m=x=>
            // is x negative?
            x<0
              // invoke m with negated input
              // to force it to a positive value
              // and negate the result to
              // convert back to negative
              ?-m(-x)
              // otherwise, does x have 4 or
              // more digits?
              :x>999
                // recursively call m with 1
                // fewer digit, then add digit
                // back to the result
                ?m(x/10)*10+x%10
                // 3 or fewer digits, move
                // the 2nd digit to the 3rd
                // and 0 put the 2nd digit
                :x-x%100+x/10%10
        )
      )
    )
    // invoke g with input 1 for leading
    (1),
    // invoke g with input -1 for following
    g(-1)
  ]
```